# templateUrl for directive when using ngdocs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set up [ngdocs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) for our projects at my company.
As a starter, I thought I should set up an example for one of our directives.

I have the ngdocs working as such, it generates documentation and all that.
What I'm wondering is, how should you provide templates for your directive when using ngdocs? My searching has found nothing about this. Which is sort of ironic (documentation tool is lacking documentation).

So, my code that generates the documentation looks like this

```js
(function (angular) {
   'use strict';

   /**
    * @ngdoc directive
    * @name EA.directive:ssn
    * @restrict E
    * @scope
    * @param {object} value The value to check for a valid ssn. This is double-binded. You will most likely want this like 'value="vm.ssn"'.
    *
    * @description
    * Textfield that gives only allows valid organisationnumbers and SSNs.
    * Checks everything except the last 4 chars.
    * The last four can be either all numbers, or 'TF##'.
    *
    * @example
    <example module="ea">
    <file name="index.html">
    <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl as vm">
      <ssn value="vm.ssn"></ssn>
    </div>
    </file>

    <file name="script.js">
    function SampleCtrl(){
      var vm = this;
      vm.ssn = "";
    }
    angular.module("ssnSample", ["ea"])
      .controller("SampleCtrl", SampleCtrl);
    </file>
    </example>
    */

   function ssn(){
      var ssnController = function(){
         var vm = this;
         init();

         function init() {
            if (vm.organisation !== undefined) {
               vm.uiMask = "?999999-9999";
               vm.pattern = /^(\d{10})$/;
               vm.errorText = "Ange ett giltigt organisationsnummer (XXXXXX-XXXX).";
            } else {
               vm.uiMask = "?99999999-**99";
               vm.pattern = /^[1-2][0,9]\d{2}([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])(\d{4}|TF\d{2})$/;
               vm.errorText = "Ange ett giltigt personnummer (YYYYMMDD-XXXX).";
            }
         }

      };

      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'src/directives/ssn/ssn.html',
         uiMask: "",
         pattern: "",
         errorText: "",
         minLength: 0,
         scope: {
            eaClass: "@",
            value: '=',
            organisation: '@',
            blur: '&'
         },
         controller: ssnController,
         controllerAs: 'vm',
         bindToController: true
      };
   }
   angular.module('ea')
      .directive('ssn', ssn);
})(angular);
```

but the result does not seem to pick up my `<ssn>` element.

here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zxrCfABbQqjWcBJKYB78?p=preview) with an example of the directive itself. It does not include the ui-mask part but as you can see the directive works.

When I generate the ng-docs, what is the path to use? My document structure is like this:

```
src
|--directives
   |--ssn
      |--ssn.js
      |--ssn.html
```

So in my `templateUrl:` what should I put? What is valid according to ngdocs?

Here is a pic of how it currently shows up:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD53J.png]

As you can see the whole 'demo' part is blank, and it shouldn't be. It should contain my `<ssn>` element, which is really just a wrapped `<input>` with fancy features.

Suggestions?

**Edit**

It has been over a week since asked, and no answers.
So far, I've tried [ng-docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdocs), [ng-doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngdoc), and [Dokular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-docular). None works.
Is documentation for AngularJS really this dead?

Comment: Fun fact: it looks like something even [AngularJS team](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.directive:uiGridMenu) is [struggling with](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/1c01e74a493eddeb06b71cb9d7f67522f209af1a/src/js/core/directives/ui-grid-menu.js#L12).

Have you find a way to make things work? I also tried the [grunt-angular-templates approach](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs/issues/187#issuecomment-253838312), but alas with no remarkable result.

Comment: @Gargaroz I never found a solution. After about two and a half week of trying to set it up, we abandoned it. Now we create our own super small demo pages for each directive we create instead. We don't get any fancy documentation page, but we can at least showcase our stuff to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the console when viewing the docs page?  Also, are you deploying the template files to the "docs" folder when you build them?  I suspect that your ssn.html isn't being found in the right location [should be able to inline it to verify].